# Solr 6 dataimport fetched 10000 records but processed only 173

Tags: solr

My first project on SOLR indexing. Importing product data from opencart ecommerce website. Its fetching correct number of records(10910) but process only 173. Appreciate if someone can help me to figure out this.

```
"Total Requests made to DataSource":"1",
"Total Rows Fetched":"10910",
"Total Documents Processed":"173",
"Total Documents Skipped":"0",
"Full Dump Started":"2016-07-27 11:22:58",
"":"Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 173 documents. Deleted 0
```

data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" user="root" password="password" />
<document name="doc">
    <entity name="dbname" transformer="RegexTransformer" query="SELECT Query " deltaImportQuery="SELECT " deltaQuery="        SELECT p.product_id as id, p.date_modified         FROM oc_product AS p         WHERE p.date_modified &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
        <field column="id" sourceColName="id" />
        <field column="model" sourceColName="model" />
        <field column="price" sourceColName="price" />
        <field column="selling_price" sourceColName="selling_price" />
        <field column="stock_status" sourceColName="stock_status" />
        <field column="name" sourceColName="name" />
        <field column="set_description" sourceColName="set_description" />
        <field column="description" sourceColName="description" />
        <field column="categories" sourceColName="categories" splitBy="," />
        <field column="category_ids" sourceColName="category_ids" splitBy="," />
        <field column="filter_ids" sourceColName="filter_ids" splitBy="," />
        <field column="filters" sourceColName="filters" splitBy="," />
        <field column="store_ids" sourceColName="store_ids" splitBy="," />
    </entity>
</document>
```

managed-schema - used default provided in configtest in solr 6.1.0 with following changes

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="model" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="price" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="selling_price" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
<field name="stock_status" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
<field name="set_description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
<field name="categories" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
<field name="category_ids" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="filter_ids" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="filters" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"   />
<field name="store_ids" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

solrconfig.xml - used default with following changes

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler-extras/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Error log:

```
Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [selling_price=299.0000,&#8203; filter_ids=12,&#8203; 13,&#8203; 19,&#8203; 24,&#8203; 43,&#8203; 58,&#8203; 62,&#8203; stock_status=In Stock,&#8203; store_ids=0,&#8203; 2,&#8203; description=Kurti length = 44 inches. No color bleed. Interlock stitching done. Side slit protection stitching done. Double bottom fold stitching done.,&#8203; filters=Long,&#8203; लॉंग,&#8203; Straight,&#8203; स्ट्रेट,&#8203; Full Sleeve,&#8203; फुल स्लीव,&#8203; Solid,&#8203; सॉलिड,&#8203; Rayon,&#8203; रेयॉन,&#8203; V Neck,&#8203; वी नेक,&#8203; Size Set,&#8203; साइज़ सेट,&#8203; set_description=1 Set = Total 5 pieces,&#8203; 1 each of 36,&#8203; 38,&#8203; 40,&#8203; 42,&#8203; 44,&#8203; price=290.0000,&#8203; name=Green Rayon Straight Solid Long V Neck Kurti,&#8203; model=GNM_JP_GMI026,&#8203; id=11856,&#8203; category_ids=0,&#8203; 61,&#8203; categories=Green Rayon Straight Solid Long V Neck Kurti,&#8203; ग्रीन रेयॉन स्ट्रेट सॉलिड लॉंग वी नेक कुर्ती,&#8203; _version_=1541015877146640386])
```

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=11856] Error adding field 'filter_ids'='12, 13, 19, 24, 43, 58, 62' msg=For input string: "12, 13, 19, 24, 43, 58, 62"

```
at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:177)

at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getLuceneDocument(AddUpdateCommand.java:82)

at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:280)

at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:214)

at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:169)

at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:68)

at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)

at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:939)

at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1094)

at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:720)

at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)

at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:74)

at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:260)

at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:524)

at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)

at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:329)

at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)

at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)

at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480)

at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12, 13, 19, 24, 43, 58, 62"

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.createField(TrieField.java:702)

at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.createFields(TrieField.java:741)

at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:47)

at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:122)
```

Comment: It might help to show (some of) your data and schema.xml and solrconfig.xml.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, Edited the question to provide config informations

Comment: Might be you have constraint violations in your data? E.g. fields with required="true" with null values in DB? Or not unique values in id field? And you have configured field "id" as id in schema.xml, I suppose?

Comment: I am sure I have 10910 unique product id's in DB and query return 10910 unique products when I run it PHPMYADMIN

Comment: I used  batchSize="-1" in data source but no luck

Comment: Why not script it using Python or Perl? Get rows from the DB, and POST each row to Solr.

Comment: I have removed transformer="RegexTransformer" from data-config and now its showing me error  "Total Documents Failed": "10737" and that can give any clue, I gone to log and see error message. Editing the post for that error message.

Comment: Seems, i found the problem...my query return filter_id in comma separated values like 23, 17, 22 and having data type of filter_ids int along with multivalue=true, what data type I should use these kind of fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, I was using data type integer for fields category_ids, filter_ids and assigning them comma separated values. It will not work although I used multiValued=true and SpiltBy comma.

So the only product were indexed which have single values for these fields.

I changed data type to string and all records indexed.

Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 10910 documents. Deleted 0 documents. (Duration: 28s)
Requests: 1 , Fetched: 10,910 390/s, Skipped: 0 , Processed: 10,910 390/s
Started: 2 minutes ago

Thank you [Uwe Allner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2621706/uwe-allner) to help on this.